# Horizontal carousel in hangouts chat

Tags: carousel, horizontallist, google-hangouts

I'd like to send a message to a hangauts-chat client containing two images.

I use this code:

```
{"cards":
  [
    {
      "header":{"title":"TITOLO 1","subtitle":"Sottotitolo 1"},
      "sections":
      [
       {"widgets":
        [
         {"image":{"imageUrl":"https://picsum.photos/200/200/?image=653"}},
         {"buttons":
           [
             {"textButton":{"text":"SCELTA A1","onClick":{"action":{"actionMethodName":"carousel A1"}}}},
             {"textButton":{"text":"SCELTA B1","onClick":{"openLink":{"url":"http://www.quix.it"}}}}
           ]
          }
        ]
       }
      ]
    },
    {
      "header":{"title":"TITOLO 2","subtitle":"Sottotitolo 2"},
      "sections":
      [
       {
         "widgets":
          [
            {"image":{"imageUrl":"https://picsum.photos/200/200/?image=7"}},
            {"buttons":
             [
              {"textButton":{"text":"SCELTA A2","onClick":{"action":{"actionMethodName":"carousel A2"}}}},
              {"textButton":{"text":"SCELTA B2","onClick":{"openLink":{"url":"http://www.quix.it"}}}}
             ]
            }
          ]
       }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but the images are displayed one below the other

[send message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKYnN.jpg)

I would like to see them aligned horizontally
as in the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OodkS.jpg)

Have you any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is and there will be any possibility to do this. As for Slack, Hangouts Chat design is based on "vertical display". We have to accept it and adapt :)